# Efficient way to convert a column into datetime

Tags: python, datetime

I have a dataframe with a column (object) having values `18-JUN-18 12.00.00.000000000 AM`.

I need to get the only the "18-JUN-18" and then convert the column as Datetime.

Below code is taking lot of time as my dataframe is huge :

```
frame['PURCHASE_DATE'] = frame['PURCHASE_DATE'].apply(lambda x: str(x)[:10])
frame['PURCHASE_DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(frame.PURCHASE_DATE)
```

Is there a way to optimize it?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `strptime` to directly convert the date:

```py
from datetime import datetime

frame['PURCHASE_DATE'] = datetime.strptime(frame['PURCHASE_DATE'][:9], '%d-%b-%y')
```

I'm not sure this is more efficient though.